# Could trophy hunting lead to deer evolving to lack antlers?

Tags: evolution, ecology

There was a recent paper in *Science* which showed that elephants are quickly evolving tusklessness because elephant hunting imposes selective pressure against having tusks:

Shane C. Campbell-Staton et al., Ivory poaching and the rapid evolution of tusklessness in African elephants.Science 374,483-487(2021). DOI:10.1126/science.abe7389

Is it plausible that trophy hunting among deer (particularly bucks) for their antlers could lead to a similar evolutionary process? Or do the differing population sizes and selective pressures make such a thing unlikely? Are bucks' antlers relatively beneficial to their mating success, compared to the increased risk of getting killed by a hunter?

Comment: There's a big difference between hunting for a trophy and killing anything that has antlers; as elephants are killed for ivory - the poachers don't care about how much, just in getting some. Trophy deer tend to be much older (i.e. already sired young), so the genes passed on already. I have no scientific backing for this, just a little deer hunting experience.

Comment: @bob1 -- thanks, and please feel free to make this an answer!

Comment: thanks - i'll decline as I don't have any references to back it up, though I am sure there is literature on this somewhere in the scientific annals.